# Aggregation in Regex using replace

Tags: regex

Is it possible to aggregate using Regex replace.

i.e.

Input:

```
 Experience <tag>Nikon</tag>'s new <tag>Advanced</tag> <tag>Scene</tag>  
 <tag>Recognition</tag> <tag>System</tag> featuring a 91,000 pixel <tag>RGB</tag> light 
 meter capable of rendering unprecedented levels of accuracy to <tag>AF</tag>, 
 <tag>AE</tag>, i <tag>TTL</tag> flash <tag>control</tag>, <tag>face</tag> 
 <tag>recognition</tag> and auto <tag>white</tag> <tag>balance</tag>.
```

Result:

```
 Experience <tag>Nikon</tag>'s new <tag>Advanced Scene Recognition System</tag>    
 featuring a 91,000 pixel <tag>RGB</tag> light meter capable of rendering unprecedented    
 levels of accuracy to <tag>AF</tag>, <tag>AE</tag>, i <tag>TTL</tag> flash 
 <tag>control</tag>, <tag>face recognition</tag> and auto <tag>white balance</tag>.
```

It is trying to aggregate continues < tag > nodes separated by space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to consolidate the tags that have been incorrectly tagged separately, why don't you try:

```
/<\/tag>\s<tag>/\s/g
```

?

Comment: Thanks Julian, didn't come to my mind at first, I replaced </tag>( {1,3})<tag> to $1 and works like charm! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Although you're not supposed to use regular expressions to parse XML/HTML, it looks like you want to replace

```
</tag>(\s*)<tag>
```

with

```
\1
```

with whatever escaping you may need to apply to the `/` in `</tag>` (so `<\/tag>` maybe).